# How do I write a text file into a Jar that is not currently running in the JVM

Tags: java, dynamic, configuration, jar, jvm

I have a Jar (info.jar) that runs and asks the user some information.

this information is supposed to be written to a text file saved inside another jar (act.jar) that is not running.  act.jar can then be run with the settings retrieved from info.jar and be distributed as a single file without the need for external configurations.

does anyone know how I can go about writing my configuration to this other jar file?

I have not yet tried anything because I do not know how to access files in a different jar.
all material I have found are for writing to a running jar.

Comment: why do you need to write into jar /

Comment: Do you mean like `jar -uf act.jar file-to-add-or-update`?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey yes, but i want to be able to do it without command lining it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAR files are just ZIP files. You should be able to use the classes in the  [`java.util.zip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) package to do what you want. A [quick google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20util%20zip) turns up a bunch of posts about how to use the package.

Answer (score 0):

Jar files are zip files with some extra meta information.

Therefore you can just treat it as a zip file using the zip related methods in the runtime environment,

That said, however, the idea of using jar files to save user provided information is a bit unusual.  What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: i am trying to keep it all 1 file, configurations are internal